# Centring nav on page isn't working?

Tags: css, navigation, center

I'm having a nightmare trying to center a nav on a web page. The code is as follows:

```
HTML:
<div class="header">
<div class="header-inner">
<div class="logo">
</div><!-- logo -->
<div class="toggle">
<a class="toggleMenu" href="#">Menu</a>
</div><!-- toggle -->
<div class="nav"> 
<div class="menu-menu-1-container">
<ul id="menu-menu-1" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-5" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-5"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-6" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-6"><a href="#">Sample Page</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-7" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-7"><a href="#">Stat</a></li>
</ul>
</div>                            
</div><!-- nav --><div class="clear"></div>
                </div><!-- header-inner -->
        </div><!-- header -->
```

CSS:

```
 .header .header-inner {
     margin: 0px auto;
     padding: 0px;
     position: relative;
     width: 1160px;
 }

.header .header-inner .nav {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
}
```

Can anyone please advise how the nav can be centred on the page? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: do you want them all in a line or stacked and centered on the page?

Comment: All in a line and centered on the page if possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to set .nav ul to text-align:center which centers all the li's within the ul. Then set the .nav ul li to display: inline-block; which wraps up each li to the width that you set so it doesn't take up the entire space. I set your width to % to make it mobile but you can use pixels if you would like http://jsfiddle.net/2k8y63xe/

css:

```
 .header .header-inner {
 margin: 0px auto;
 padding: 0px;
 position: relative;
 }

.header .header-inner .nav {
margin: 0px auto;
padding: 0px;
}

.nav ul { margin: 0px auto; padding: 0px; text-align: center;}
.nav ul li { text-align: center; text-decoration:none; list-style-type:none;    display: inline-block; width: 30%;}
```

Comment: Legend, very well explained! Thanks very much!

Comment: No problem, let me know if you have any other questions

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear to me what you'd like- and it seems you have some CSS classes without HTML divs (There's no 'Header' or 'Header-Inner' in your HTML).  However, lets just take the div 'nav' which I think you want to center:

So first, because by default the div fills 100% width, we'll need to shrink that down.  Otherwise centering will do nothing- something that's 100% width is, of course, already centered.  Then we simply make margin-left and margin-right auto.  As an example:

```
.nav {
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   width: 20%;
}
```